# Bounding boxes around characters for tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to do number plate recognition using tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1. In tesseract documentation, it is told to create box files in the form      . I tried using "makebox" function. But, it is not detecting every character properly. Then, somewhere i read that this function is for version 3.x.

I later tried "wordstrbox" function. But the box file which is created in this way is empty. Can someone tell me how to create box files for tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pytesseract.image_to_data()`

```
import pytesseract
import cv2
from pytesseract import Output

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
d = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type=Output.DICT)
n_boxes = len(d['level'])
for i in range(n_boxes):
    (text,x,y,w,h) = (d['text'][i],d['left'][i],d['top'][i],d['width'][i],d['height'][i])
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h) , (0,255,0), 2)
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitkey(0)
```

Among the data returned by pytesseract.image_to_data():

- `left` is the distance from the upper-left corner of the bounding box,
  to the left border of the image.
- `top` is the distance from the upper-left corner of the bounding box,
  to the top border of the image.
- `width` and `height` are the width and height of the bounding box.
- `conf` is the model's confidence for the prediction for the word within
  that bounding box. If `conf` is -1, that means that the corresponding
  bounding box contains a block of text, rather than just a single
  word.

The bounding boxes returned by `pytesseract.image_to_boxes()` enclose letters so I believe `pytesseract.image_to_data()` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I've found AlfyFaisy's answer very helpful and just wanted to share the code to view the bounding boxes of single characters. The differences regard the keys of the dictionary that is output by the `image_to_boxes` method:

```
import pytesseract
import cv2
from pytesseract import Output

img = cv2.imread('image.png')
height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]

d = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(img, output_type=Output.DICT)
n_boxes = len(d['char'])
for i in range(n_boxes):
    (text,x1,y2,x2,y1) = (d['char'][i],d['left'][i],d['top'][i],d['right'][i],d['bottom'][i])
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x1,height-y1), (x2,height-y2) , (0,255,0), 2)
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

At least on my machine (Python 3.6.8, cv2 4.1.0) the cv2 method is `waitKey(0)` with a capital K.

This is the output I got:

[image: output]